# Blur Background on Lifting a Card

Tags: jquery

### What I'm working on

I am currently working on a basic card game.  I have gotten done some of the styling but am struggling with a couple of things in jQuery.

### Question

There are two major issues with the code.

1. When you lift a card and drag it on top of another, the divs overlap, oddly.
2. I wish to blur the rest of body when you pickup and start dragging a card.  I have no idea how to start doing that.  I have googled around a bit and haven't made any progress.

### Code

**Aside:** Any suggestion on how to improve the code is encouraged.

```js
cards = [{
    "name": "Mutant",
    "attack": 500,
    "defense": 100,
    "health": 1000,
    "img": "http://neil.computer/stack/bg2.jpg",
    "effects": {

    },
  },
  {
    "name": "Angry Mom",
    "attack": 500,
    "defense": 100,
    "health": 9001,
    "img": "http://neil.computer/stack/bg3.jpg",
    "effects": {

    },
  }
];

function render($selector, card) {
  $(`
  <div class="name front">` + card["name"] + `</div>
  <div class="attack front"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>` + card["attack"] + `</div>
  <div class="defense front"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>` + card["defense"] + `</div>
  <div class="health front"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>` + card["health"] + `</div>`).appendTo($selector);
  $selector.css({
    "background-image": "url(" + card["img"] + ")",
  });
}

render($(".card").draggable(), cards[1]);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Macondo);
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);

body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.card {
font-family:Macondo, cursive;
position:relative;
width:200px;
height:200px;
border:1px solid #000;
border-radius:4px;
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center center;
}

.card .front {
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
color:#FFF;
font-size:20px;
background:rgba(77,77,77,.7);
border:1px solid #000;
-webkit-transition:background .1s;
transition:background .5s;
padding:2px;
}

.card:hover .front {
background:rgba(55,55,55,.9);
-webkit-transition:background .1s;
transition:background .5s;
}

.card .front i {
margin-right:6px;
}

.card .name {
top:0;
left:0;
text-align:center;
font-weight:700;
border-radius:2px 2px 0 0;
width:calc(100%-6px);
}

.card .attack {
border-radius:0 5px 0 2px;
left:0;
bottom:0;
}

.card .defense {
border-radius:5px 0 2px 0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
}

.card .health {
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
</div>
<div class="card">
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Try this working snippet.

```js
cards = [{
    "name": "Mutant",
    "attack": 500,
    "defense": 100,
    "health": 1000,
    "img": "http://neil.computer/stack/bg2.jpg",
    "effects": {

    },
     },
     {
    "name": "Angry Mom",
    "attack": 500,
    "defense": 100,
    "health": 9001,
    "img": "http://neil.computer/stack/bg3.jpg",
    "effects": {

    },
     }
   ];

 renderCards( cards );

 $(document).on("drag", ".card", function(){ 
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.masking').addClass('mask');
 });

 $('.masking').on("click", function(){ 
  $(this).removeClass('mask');
  $('.card').removeClass('active');
 });
   
 function renderCards( cards ) {
  $( cards ).each(function( index ) {
   var card  = cards[index];
   var cardDiv = $('<div class="card" />');
   
   $('<div class="name front">' + card["name"] + '</div><div class="attack front"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + card["attack"] + '</div><div class="defense front"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + card["defense"] + '</div><div class="health front"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + card["health"] + '</div>').appendTo(cardDiv);
   
   cardDiv.css({"background-image": "url(" + card["img"] + ")"}).draggable().appendTo('.cards');
  });
 }
```

```css
 @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Macondo);
 @import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
 @import url(https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css);

 body {
  background: #000;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
  
 .card {
  font-family:Macondo, cursive;
  position:relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-radius:4px;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center center;
  margin: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
 }
 .card.active{
  z-index: 3;
 }

 .card .front {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:20px;
  background:rgba(77,77,77,.7);
  border:1px solid #000;
  -webkit-transition:background .1s;
  transition:background .5s;
  padding:2px;
 }

 .card:hover .front {
  background:rgba(55,55,55,.9);
  -webkit-transition:background .1s;
  transition:background .5s;
 }

 .card .front i {
  margin-right:6px;
 }

 .card .name {
  top:0;
  left:0;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:700;
  border-radius:2px 2px 0 0;
  width:calc(100%-6px);
 }

 .card .attack {
  border-radius:0 5px 0 2px;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
 }

 .card .defense {
  border-radius:5px 0 2px 0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
 }

 .card .health {
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  border-radius:5px;
 }
 
 .mask {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;

  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  -moz-filter: blur(8px);
  -o-filter: blur(8px);
  -ms-filter: blur(8px);
  z-index: 2;
 }
```

```html
<div class="masking"></div>
<div class="cards"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```